# Import Word (.DOC and .DOCX) document files into MySQL Server Database using OpenXML

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-word, openxml

I need to import `Word` (.DOC and .DOCX) document files into `MySQL Server Database` directly using `OpenXML`.

In this code I have set an `regexp` is to check if a line starts with a whitespace, a letter, the bullet character or the - character or number

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
{
    body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    contents = "";
    
    var reg = new Regex(@"^[\s\p{L}\d•-]");

    foreach (Paragraph co in
                wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(somethingElse => 
                reg.IsMatch(somethingElse.InnerText)))
    {
        contents += co.InnerText + "<br />";
        //insert contents into database;
    }
}
```

But this code import only the text contained in `Word` (.DOC and .DOCX) document files.

If on the `Word` file I have

1. List 1
2. List 2
3. List 3

or

- List 4
- List 5
- List 6

on the table of `MySQL Server Database`

```
+----------+
| contents |
+----------+
| List 1   |
| List 2   |
| List 3   |
| List 4   |
| List 5   |
| List 6   |
+----------+
6 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

**My problems using this code:**

1. I need that each paragraph corresponds to a row of the table
   MySQL... but each new line in word creates a new row in the database
   table...
2. Importing correctly the text contained in Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
   document files, including line starts with the bullet character or
   the - character or number...

In this moment all line starts with a bullet character or the - character or number are imported without the bullet character or the - character or number...

In case of line starts with the bullet character or the - character or number... I need this result..

```
+------------+----------+ 
| contents   | tID      | 
+------------+----------+ 
| 1.List 1   |          |
| 2.List 2   | 1        | 
| 3.List 3   |          | 
+------------+----------+ 
| ●List 4    |          | 
| ●List 5    | 2        | 
| ●List 6    |          |
+------------+----------+ 
2 rows in set
```

**Structure of word DOCX**

```
UTC


Section 1 - Events 
 
- Para 1.1 
1.  test 1
2.  test 2
3.  test 3
 
 
Section 2 - Safety 
 
- Para 2.1
•   test 4
•   test 5
•   test 6

Section 3 - Economics 
 
- Para 3.1 
Contents 3.1 
 
Section 4 – Resource

- Para 4.1 
Contents 4.1

Section 5 - Service 
 
- Para 5.1
Contents 5.1
```

**Output required**

```
+-----------------------+----------+ 
| contents              | tID      | 
+-----------------------+----------+ 
| UTC                   |    1     |
+-----------------------+----------+
|Section 1 - Events     |    2     |
+-----------------------+----------+
|- Para 1.1             |    3     |
+-----------------------+----------+
| 1.test 1              |          |
| 2.test 2              |    4     | 
| 3.test 3              |          | 
+-----------------------+----------+ 
|Section 2 - Safety     |    5     |
+-----------------------+----------+
|- Para 2.1             |    6     |
+-----------------------+----------+
| ●test 4               |          | 
| ●test 5               |    7     | 
| ●test 6               |          |
+-----------------------+ ---------+
|Section 3 - Economics  |    8     |
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|- Para 3.1             |    9     |
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|Contents 3.1           |   10     | 
+-----------------------+ ---------+  
|Section 4 – Resource   |   11     |
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|- Para 4.1             |   12     | 
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|Contents 4.1           |   13     |
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|Section 5 - Service    |   14     |
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|- Para 5.1             |   15     |
+-----------------------+ ---------+ 
|Contents 5.1           |   16     | 
+-----------------------+ ---------+
```

Comment: This doesn't look like OpenXML to me.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Comment: Trying to identify paragraph formats via RegEx seems very brittle to me - [How to retrieve paragraphs from an Office Open XML document (LINQ to XML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/retrieve-paragraphs-office-open-xml-document)

Comment: @Filburt thansk for reply. I have tried your suggestion using word test file. But the output in the debug vs2109 is empty...

Comment: Are you trying to save the entire .doc or .docx file to the database?

Comment: @user9938 Yes Sir!

Comment: Your code rather looks like you try to only save specific parts of your document; not the entire document as a whole.

Comment: @Filburt thanks for reply. This code saving entire document doxc on the database table, with some inconsistencies. Please see **My problems using this code:** in the question...